# Kraus Operator for two-qubit basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, quantum-information, linear-algebra

Let A and B each be a single qubit so that $\mathbb{H_{AB}}$ is a two-qubit system. In the basis {$|\uparrow\uparrow>,|\uparrow\downarrow>,|\downarrow\uparrow>,|\downarrow\downarrow>$, the Kraus operators are defined as $K_\uparrow=\mathbb{I_A}\otimes<\uparrow|_B $ and $K_\downarrow=\mathbb{I_A}\otimes<\downarrow|_B $. What is $\mathbb{I_A}$ here in the form of a matrix. I am confused because when I use $A=\begin{pmatrix}{ 1 \\ 0}\end{pmatrix}$, $B=\begin{pmatrix}{ 0 \\ 1}\end{pmatrix}$ and
$\mathbb{I_A} = \begin{pmatrix}   1 & 0\\    0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. I don't get the right answers.

The answers are given as:

$K_\uparrow=\begin{pmatrix}   1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$

and

$K_\downarrow=\begin{pmatrix}   0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\    0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$

This calculation that I am trying to do is from the page 14 of the paper: 'Entanglement entropy and non-local duality: Quantum channels and quantum algebras
', [arXiv:2207.12436](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.12436).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a notation problem.They are writing

$K_\uparrow=\mathbb{I_A}\otimes<\uparrow|_B $

but doing:

$K_\uparrow=<\uparrow|_B\otimes\mathbb{I_A} $

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\langle\uparrow|_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_B$ is a row vector, so that the tensorial product inside $K_\uparrow$ is calculated as a [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Definition), i.e.
$$
K_\uparrow 
   = 1_A \otimes \langle\uparrow|_B 
   = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 
     \end{pmatrix}
     \otimes
     \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0
     \end{pmatrix}
   = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} 
      & 0 \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}
     \end{pmatrix}
   = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 & 0 
     \end{pmatrix}
$$
Of course, the same procedure applies to $K_\downarrow$.

Comment: In the second row if you multiply 0.(1 0) then you get (0 0), not (0 1) right